# How to do this expandable RecyclerView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, expandable

I am trying to create this effect:

[minimised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdfHX.png) ==>
[maximised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykb2f.png)

I was looking for a library I can use so I can avoid reinventing the wheel. If you have any recommendations or advice, please let me know!

Right now I am using an expandablelistview and managed to get to [this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbbKW.jpg). As you can see I can't put the indicator on the right and the list item dividers/separators are clunky. I've done that by having my first child-view as a title for the whole thing:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int exerciseId, int setId, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Context parentContext = parent.getContext();
    int itemSetID = R.layout.item_exercise_set;

    if (view == null) 
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parentContext).inflate(itemSetID, parent, false);

    SetHolder holder = new SetHolder(view);
    if(setId == 0)
        holder.setTitle();
    else{
        Set set = (Set) getChild(exerciseId, setId - 1);
        holder.setSet(set);
    }

    return view;
}
```

How can I do this better? I am trying to have everything clean and not complicated.

Many Thanks,
Martin

Comment: You can do this with a recycler view by playing with visibility, plus, it will allow you to have more customization.

Answer (score 0):

Expandable ListView becomes all complicated once there are different kind of child layout associated with it, so the best alternative to get the same effect is RecyclerView with animations which gives the same effect of expandable ListView with all the enhancements of RecyclerView.

Following blog post clearly explains how to do it, hope you can follow this
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/expandable-recyclerview-android/

Comment: As the size of the set is not a fixed value, I'm using a listView for them. In other words I'll have to have a recyclerView within the viewHolder of the recyclerView. Wouldn't that overcomplicate the code, as I will have to manage yet another adapter?